# How do I get rid of the Start Menu "zombie" icon?

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

Windows 7 has a large icon above the username on the right-hand pane of the Start menu. By default it is a faceless torso in a blue collarless shirt that I call the "zombie icon". (I don't know the icon's real name: [it's so useless that Microsoft doesn't even discuss it when describing the Start menu](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/The-Start-menu-overview). (Although "Molly Clark" has a zinnia icon instead of a zombie icon.)

The zombie icon fades from one pointless icon to another as you move your mouse over "Documents", "Computer", "Devices and Printers" etc. This icon is a waste of space and the fades are distracting.

How do I make it go away?

Comment: OK, I figured out how to replace the zombie with a blank png. Now I have an icon that looks like a powered-off classic iMac.

I'd still prefer the whole thing to go away.

Comment: You can use Group Policy settings to remove your name from the start menu.  I think this makes the "zombie" go away.

Comment: I'm not on a domain so I needed this link http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3652-local-group-policy-editor-open.html to open the Local Group Policy Editor. Removing name from Start menu is XP/2003 only; removing the user directory link (newer OS equiv) does get rid of the menu item, but it doesn't get rid of the icon! Thanks, though, I am more inclined to try something that uses built-in MS tools.

Comment: Replace zombie icon with a vampire icon... a vampire sucking up all that useful space!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try one of those:

- http://www.vistax64.com/general-discussion/194952-hide-remove-user-picture-start-menu.html
- http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/11213-remove-user-picture-start-menu.html
- http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/619531-remove-start-menu-user-picture-frame/

Comment: Thanks! These may require more hacking then I can justify doing (it's a development box...I need to avoid unnecessary OS modifications) but you definitely got me on the right track on what needs to be done. Other useful links: Windows style builder (http://www.vistastylebuilder.com/index.html) and PandaX's list of required changes (http://stylehacks.deviantart.com/art/Win7-Disable-User-Picture-146555450)

Comment: True, I tried to stay away from external software as those might increase resource usage.